# How do I call an ActionScript class from an included SWF file from javascript with AIR app?

Tags: javascript, class, air, flash, instantiation

I have an AIR app that includes blooddy_crypto_0.3.5.swf

```
<script src="lib/MD5/blooddy_crypto_0.3.5.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></script>
```

I want to calculate the MD5 hash of a byte array I'll read via a filestream.

What I can't figure out is HOW to call the Md5 function.

swfdump blooddy_crypto_0.3.5.swf

shows

**by/blooddy/crypto/MD5", lazy load**

So, how do I instantiate this function from my javascript?

I've read [How to access Actionscript from Javascript in Adobe AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754542/how-to-access-actionscript-from-javascript-in-adobe-air)
and [How to invoke an ActionScript method from JavaScript (HTMLLoader) object in AIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448441/how-to-invoke-an-actionscript-method-from-javascript-htmlloader-object-in-air)

But it didn't really help, I'm nOT trying to manipulate a DOM object but run a piece of Math ;)

Any help appreciated.